# MySQL different treatment between VarChar(255) and VarChar(65536)

Tags: mysql, varchar

Does anyone know the difference between using VarChar(255) and VarChar(65536) ?

Here's what I know so far :

- VarChar(255) will only use one byte for size
- VarChar(65536) will use two bytes for size
- VarChar(65536) exists only since MySQL 5.0.3
- MySQL use a different treatment between 255 and 65536 (don't know the difference though)

What I'm not sure of if is it any performance difference between those varchars.

Let's say I would like to create a table with a multiple type of row.
Using an enum with 'data_type1' and 'data_type2'

data_type1 will never have more than 255 characters in the varchar
data_type2 will mostly have more than 255 characters in the varchar

Which solution table would be better ?

```
id (int) - autoincrement
type (enum : data_type1, data_type2)
msg (varchar(255))
data (TEXT)
```

Using only the 'data' column when type == data_type2 ?

or

```
id (int) - autoincrement
type (enum : data_type1, data_type2)
msg (varchar(65536))
```

Using 'msg' column whatever type is present ?

The type column is actually wanted on both solution for treatment purpose.

EDIT :

**When type == data_type2, the data stored will actually never be over 10000 characters**

EDIT 2 :

**I'm not looking to search in columns msg and data**

This is a simple question about storage performance, not indexes or search perf...

Comment: I can't really figure out what you're asking.

Comment: I guess, in a nutshell my question is : Which table is better between 1 and 2 for storing 2 data type differing in size

Comment: Semantically, version 2.

Comment: Yeah I guess so, that's why I have writted it, but if solution 1 is faster to fetch, who cares about semantics ;)

Comment: I do! Also, it's probably not. It'll not be your bottleneck anyway. If you _really_ care, profile it. Otherwise, just write it and move on to more important things.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You mentioned some things that are true, I'll explain how VARCHAR works.

If you specify VARCHAR(60) that means it can hold up to 60 characters. If it contains less characters, let's say 50 - then MySQL uses 50 bytes to store the data instead of 60.

It's quite the opposite with CHAR(60) - it reserves 60 bytes regardless of the length of the string you want to save.

Now, how does VARCHAR work? If you specify it as VARCHAR(255), that means that the column will reserve 1 byte + length of the string bytes.
That 1 byte indicates how long the string is. 1 byte = you can have from 0 - 255 values stored (2 to the power of 8 = 256).

As for VARCHAR that is above 255, you need to somehow store how many bytes are being used. Since 1 byte can store only up to 256 distinct values (0 - 255), you need to use two bytes. Two to the power of 16 = 65536, which means you can store any string up to that size and then it adds up 2 bytes to indicate how long the string is.

So, to cut it short - performance difference is that if you have VARCHAR(65536) and  you use 200 bytes to store the text - you are wasting that 1 extra byte that VARCHAR(65536) will use.
One might think "oh, but that's just 1 byte, who cares about that". A lot of people do actually - imagine having several VARCHAR columns on a table that's got 50 million records. Say you got 3 varchar columns, each wastes additional byte - that's 3 bytes * 50 million ~ 144 megabytes of wasted space. The funny thing is, it's not just wasted space. It also contributes to processing overhead and using extra RAM when you want to read something.
And who says there's going to be only 1 table in your DB that's going to get large?

Knowing this information might help you deciding yourself what's the best to use.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html if you didn't check it before, it explains how every data type is stored and how much space it requires.

Comment: won't it slow things up having a TEXT field set to NULL if I'm fetching data_type1 ? And would it be as fast, getting a varchar(65536) or a TEXT ?

Comment: The differences are negligible here, you are talking about performance in *retrieving* the row after you find it but you have completely forgotten about *finding* the row you want to retrieve. In terms of scale, you're optimizing in the wrong playing field. What is it exactly that you're doing? It kind of sounds like strongly typed EAV data model that you've stumbled upon, can you clarify a bit so i can point you to the right direction?

Comment: What I'm worry about in fact is that this table will be queried a LOT ! The row life cycle is pretty simple, INSERT-SELECT-DELETE (it is a Queue actually). Right now we are facing 300K/hour for each action (300k insert, 300k select, 300k delete)/hour. I would like to have the best performance in adding and deleting along with select of course (but select is not really what I'm worried about actually)

Comment: What database engine are you using? If it's InnoDB, then if your DELETEs and SELECTs are based on primary key lookup (WHERE id = 123), then InnoDB will be extremely fast and data type of varchar / text won't make a difference there. If it's MyISAM then INSERTs will be quick as formula 1 but other bits might crash, whereas SELECTs based on primary key will be much slower than ones based on InnoDB.

Comment: it is InnoDB with primary key lookup. So I guess I'm worry for nothing... I'll see when I'm done ;) Thanks

Comment: The 144 MB are relativly small compared to about 28 gigabytes for the data of the 3 varchar columns.

Answer (score -1):

IMO it's better to use VARCHAR over any other string type, because TEXT has a size limit and CHAR reserves space on disk.  VARCHAR only uses space for the character you have entered.

Comment: Sorry, it's not true, you have the wrong information. CHAR will indeed "reserve" the space, TEXT won't, it resembles to how VARCHAR works.

Comment: so that's mean that if I use field type TEXT and I store a value of 300 characters, TEXT will fit this size? or, I will waste some space?

Comment: Old thread, but saw this and figured I'd comment. The only difference between `varchar` and `text` is the max amount of data that can be stored.

varchar(max) - Variable width character string - max size 1,073,741,824 characters


text - Variable width character string - 2GB of text data